# Filter data in Postgre using ILIKE with an Apostrophe sign

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have some error in my SQL statement when it comes filtering data with an Apostrophe sign within the data.

How to fix this kind of error sample?

```
Select * from table_1 where name ilike '%sam'le%'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE name ILIKE '%sam''le%';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE name ILIKE $$%sam'le%$$;
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS).